# Why does the hexadecimal format specifier produce the wrong output in VS2013 for x86

Tags: c

I ran into an unusual problem with printf in VS2013 which I have isolated in the small test case below.

When built with the x64 compiler everything is fine.  When built for 32-bit one of the variables is printed incorrectly.  This happens whether built from within Visual Studio itself or using cl at the command line.  It also happens with optimisations disabled.

The problem is the hexadecimal format specifier (or possibly the UINT64) in the printf.  When I remove the format specifier and the variable from the call it works as expected.  This is the same behaviour as splitting up the calls to printf, which also works correctly.

Output from the command line showing the misbehaviour is below.  Note that `content_layout` is printed differently, first as zero (wrong) then as one (correct).

**My question** - am I doing something wrong in the code or is the compiler producing the wrong output on x86?

Output from cl and running the program:

```
## Compile, disable optimisation with /Od
C:\Path\TestStruct>cl /Od main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.40629.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe
main.obj

C:\Path\TestStruct>main.exe

## This line is incorrect and prints zero for content_layout
handoff_size: 29336, handoff_location: 0xc8ff8000, content_layout: 0, content_type: 1

## These two lines are correct and print one for content_layout
## Note these are split up into two calls to printf()
handoff size: 29336, handoff_location: 0xc8ff8000
content_layout: 1, content_type: 1
```

The test case code is below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Don't allow compiler to align structs - pack members on byte boundary
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct _acpi_header {
  char signature[4];
  UINT32 length;
  UINT8 revision;
  UINT8 checksum;
  char oem_id[6];
  char oem_table_id[8];
  UINT32 oem_revision;
  UINT32 creator_id;
  UINT32 creator_revision;
} acpi_header_t;

typedef struct _wpbt_header {
  UINT32 handoff_size;
  UINT64 handoff_location;
  UINT8 content_layout;
  UINT8 content_type;
} wpbt_header_t;

int main(void) {
  acpi_header_t *acpi_header;
  wpbt_header_t *wpbt_header;

  BYTE lpBuf[] = {
    0x57, 0x50, 0x42, 0x54, 0x38, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xe4, 0x41, 0x42, 0x54, 0x2d, 0x4e, 0x54,
    0x41, 0x42, 0x54, 0x2d, 0x57, 0x50, 0x42, 0x54, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x42, 0x54, 0x57,
    0x02, 0x04, 0x12, 0x20, 0x98, 0x72, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff, 0xc8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    0x01, 0x01, 0x04, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
  };

  acpi_header = (acpi_header_t*)(lpBuf);
  wpbt_header = (wpbt_header_t*)(lpBuf + sizeof(acpi_header_t));

  // Does not work - content_layout is printed as 0 (zero)
  printf("handoff_size: %lu, handoff_location: 0x%x, content_layout: %u, content_type: %u\r\n", wpbt_header->handoff_size, 
    wpbt_header->handoff_location, wpbt_header->content_layout, wpbt_header->content_type);

  // Works - content_layout is printed as 1
  printf("handoff size: %lu, handoff_location: 0x%x\r\n", wpbt_header->handoff_size, wpbt_header->handoff_location);
  printf("content_layout: %u, content_type: %u", wpbt_header->content_layout, wpbt_header->content_type);

  getchar();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Damn, didn't see that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem that you are using the wrong [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format to print the single bytes.

If you follow the linked reference and check the `"%u"` format you will see that without any prefix it prints an `unsigned int` and not a `UINT8` (which is probably an `unsigned char`). The correct format for `unsigned char` is `"%hhu"`.

However, C have standardized a set of [predefined format macros](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants) that you should be using instead for fixed-width types. For printing unsigned 8-bit bytes, you should use `PRIu8`:

```
printf("content_layout: %" PRIu8 ", content_type: %" PRIu8 "\n",
       wpbt_header->content_layout, wpbt_header->content_type);
```

Comment: Thank you - this was indeed the problem.  However the inconsistent behaviour from the x86 compiler is puzzling.. it seems to do the "right" thing in the second case despite the wrong format specifiers.

Comment: `%u` should work for `unsigned char`  (according to the usual interpretation of the standard, it is in fact guaranteed to work, because `unsigned char` promotes to a non-negative `int`, and non-negative `int` has the same size & representation as the unsigned `int` with the same value).

Comment: The specifier for `uint64_t` (assuming `UINT64_T` is the same) is `"%" PRI64x` .  `%llx` is actually for `long long unsigned int` which could be larger than 64bit.

Comment: @David perhaps the 32-bit ver stores the value in the same memory location for 32-bit int as it would for 64-bit int, and since your system is little-endian it appears to work. The 64bit ver might use 64bit registers only for 64bit values, or different stack alignment, or something.

Comment: There is a project [msinttypes](https://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/) to port the C99 `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` headers to earlier versions of Visual Studio. It doesn't turn VC into a C99 compiler, but it may help with porting code.

Answer (score 2):

The format specifier for `handoff_location` is incorrect. `%x` is for `int` which is only 32 bits in the x86 version of the code. But you are pushing a 64 bit int on to the stack which means that, when printf processes it, it "leaves behind" the top four bytes of `hand_off_location` and interprets them as the `content_layout`. In turn `content_layout` is actually interpreted as `content_type` and `content_type` is ignored.

What I would do is use `%llx` and cast `handoff_location` to `unsigned long long`.

Another point — which you seem to have got away with in this case — is that the compiler is free to put padding bytes between members of a struct. You should never just overlay a struct onto a binary buffer and hope it works.

The 64 bit version could be working for one of three reasons:

- `int` is 64 bits wide
- items are pushed on to the stack with 64 bit alignment.
- the ABI for x64 uses registers to pass the first few parameters.

Comment: That is what the `#pragma` is for which works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of why this is incorrect.

Comment: I missed the `#pragma`